# Como centrar dos palabras que se encuentran en diferentes oraciones - CSS

Tags: css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Centrarla con una palabra y no por la oracion

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu código html y css? Esto podría hacerse de diferentes modos pero va a depender en gran medida de la estructura de tu html. Lee [ask] y [mcve] y Edita la pregunta para añadir el código.

Comment: Es un blucle for en django2 (Python) que renderiza en el template, el tamaño es dinamico. Y si ... ! debi poner el codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo lo he hecho a partir de 3 divisiones que tengan un `display:inline-block;` y una un `width`

```css
div.resultados div{
  display:inline-block;
}
div.equipo1{
  width:40%;
  text-align:right;
}
div.equipo2{
  width:40%;
  text-align:left;
}
div.versus{
  width:5%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="resultados">
  <div class="equipo1">Real Madrid</div>
  <div class="versus">vs</div>
  <div class="equipo2">Jueventus</div>
</div>
<div class="resultados">
  <div class="equipo1">Juventus</div>
  <div class="versus"> vs </div>
  <div class="equipo2">Manchester united</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aunque esta solución seguramente va en la línea de lo que tiene y necesita la persona que pregunta. No se debería responder a las preguntas que son demasiado amplias o deficientes en datos y que no se ajustan bien al formato/contenido del sitio. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: Gracias bro si me sirve...

Comment: @Degow no alteres el contenido original de la respuesta, eso solo le compete al quien respondió; en caso de hacerlo se considera vandalismo